# Transforming columns in R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame of transactional data of the form

```
transactions <- data.frame(transaction=c("T1","T2","T2","T3","T3","T3"),sku=c("item_a","item_b","item_c","item_a","item_b","item_d"))
```

which gives me this

```
  transaction    sku
1          T1 item_a
2          T2 item_b
3          T2 item_c
4          T3 item_a
5          T3 item_b
6          T3 item_d
```

What I would like to get as an output is this data frame:

```
output <- data.frame(transaction=c("T1","T2","T3"),sku=c("item_a","item_b item_c","item_a item_b item_d"))
```

that looks like this

```
  transaction                  sku
1          T1               item_a
2          T2        item_b item_c
3          T3 item_a item_b item_d
```

I tried various approaches, such as first using **split** on the original data frame by transactions$transaction, but I then I had trouble extracting the sku data from the resulting list. Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**: typo in the output data frame fixed. thanks to juba.

Comment: I think item_c should be item_b at the T3 row in your results ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `plyr` with `summarise`

```
require(plyr)
ddply(transactions, .(transaction), summarise, sku=paste(sku, collapse = " "))

#  transaction                  sku
# 1          T1               item_a
# 2          T2        item_b item_c
# 3          T3 item_a item_b item_d
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Arun. I had just started reading up on plyr and being able to see how ddply works on my dataset is invaluable

Answer (score 4):

This is really easy using `data.table` , which has a nice way of printing list columns

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(transactions)

DT[,list(sku = list(sku)) ,by=transaction]
##    transaction                  sku
## 1:          T1               item_a
## 2:          T2        item_b,item_c
## 3:          T3 item_a,item_b,item_d
```

If you wanted them pasted together you could also do

```
DT <- data.table(transactions)
DT[,list(sku = paste(sku, collapse = ', ')) ,by=transaction]
   transaction                  sku
1:          T1               item_a
2:          T2        item_b,item_c
3:          T3 item_a,item_b,item_d
```

`sku` will be a character vector now, not a list for each transaction

Answer (score 1):

Using `plyr` instead:

```
library(plyr)
new_trans <- ddply(
  transactions,
  .(transaction),
  transform,
  sku=paste0(sku, collapse=" ")
  )
new_trans <- unique(new_trans)
print(new_trans)
```

Comment: If you use summarise instead of transform, you don't need to use `unique` afterward.

Answer (score 1):

To add to your options, this is also easy in base R with `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(sku ~ transaction, transactions, paste, collapse = " ")
  transaction                  sku
1          T1               item_a
2          T2        item_b item_c
3          T3 item_a item_b item_d
```